SOT 23-5 Voltage regulator (?) Identification
First time poster here, grateful for any help provided.
I'm repairing this mainboard for a Roland C380 organ (Marked C 330 on pcb) and came across this point of failure. Substrate and trace repairs aside I'd like some help figuring out a suitable replacement for this 5 pin component. The board itself operates on 24v.
Regarding other possible culprits for this happening, I appreciate any input. There is definitely a short present but I figured I'd best troubleshoot with this line populated as it should be.


Unfortunately, without any other information, there's no way of knowing. The instrument doesn't have any public schematics either. This might be a moonshot request but what you could do is talk with Roland and seeing if they can help provide that sort of information. Perhaps there's a warranty or maybe they would be willing to share that information for a single component.

Moonshot is almost an understatement, yeah.
I'm still trying to figure out at least the pinout of that specific IC. This track from what I could gather relates to the input of the ADC chip (AKM5384). Other functions of the instrument itself still work so the failure isn't completely catastrophic.

Hmm... Interesting so if the keyboard still functions, have you noticed what doesn't work? That might give some clues on what that device actually is, whether it's an amplifier or voltage conversion.

What happened to that board?

I have to say, I didn't expect to find that under the satellite boards when i cracked the thing open. No idea how it happened.
